# Dynamically changing the margin-top of an element in razor pages

Tags: html, css

I'm sitting with a slight problem in my razor pages project.

I'm trying to make contact page, with two sections, one stretching across the entire page, without affecting the body element.

The first section is using position absolute, and that makes the second section stay behind the first. I wanted to know if there is a way dynamically changing "margin-top" on section 2 to be the height of section 1

Html

```css
.sit-contact-downarrow {
    fill: var(--color-second);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -22.5px;
    height: 22.5px;
    width: 150px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
.sit-contact-downarrow path {
    transform: scaleX(2);
}
.sit-contact-section {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: var(--color-second);
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
.sit-contact-section-item img {
    height: var(--iconSize);
    max-width: var(--iconSize);
    max-height: var(--iconSize);
}
.sit-contact-section-items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between
}
.sit-contact-section-item {
    word-wrap: anywhere;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(220,220,255,0.3);
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 15px 5px;
}
.sit-contact-section-item a, .sit-contact-section-item span {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.sit-contact-section-content {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <div class="sit-contact-section">
        <div class="sit-contact-section-content">
            <h1>Kontakt os</h1>
            <div class="sit-contact-section-items">
                <div class="sit-contact-section-item" id="sit-item-map">
                    <img src="~/Pictures/map.svg" />
                    <div class="sit-contact-section-item-content">
                        <h3>Find os her</h3>
                        <a href="@(Model.LocationHref)" target="_blank">@Model.LocationShow</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sit-contact-section-item" id="sit-item-phone">
                    <img src="~/Pictures/phone.svg" />
                    <div class="sit-contact-section-item-content">
                        <h3>Ring til os</h3>
                        <a href="tel:@(Model.TelephoneNumberHref)">@Model.TelephoneNumberShow</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sit-contact-section-item" id="sit-item-mail">
                    <img src="~/Pictures/email.svg" />
                    <div class="sit-contact-section-item-content">
                        <h3>Send en email</h3>
                        <a href="mailto:@(Model.MailHref)">@Model.MailShow</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <svg class="sit-contact-downarrow">
            <path d="M0 0 L37.5 22.5 L75 0 Z" />
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="sit-contact-info">
        </div>
        <div class="sit-contact-form">
            <form method="post">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <label></label>
                        <input type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label></label>
                        <input type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label></label>
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label></label>
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: is there a reason why you lay out the first section with `position`? That just broke the HTML element flow and make the second section come under the first second

Comment: I'm using position absolute because i needed a background across the entire section (I'll attach an image at the buttom of the post)

Comment: Where did you place the background image? Could you include this in your example code?

Comment: Wdym with background image? There is no images? The downarrow is the "svg" path

And the blue background color is "sit-contact-section"

Comment: Didn't you just edit the question and add an image? Is this something you're trying to achieve?

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-estrela-ub71o1?file=/index.html

Comment: I added an image of how i was trying to get it to work There is no images inserted other than the 3 icons. So the image i added is the "finished" product

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248290/discussion-between-baconbotmk1-and-konekoya).

Comment: There are quite a few things that you need to tweak, but the basic idea is that don't use position to lay out your first section. This will make your second section come right after your first one. And in order to place the SVG between the sections, you will need some modifications for the HTML as well. 
Here is the updated one of my previous codesanbox, good luck
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-estrela-ub71o1?file=/index.html

Comment: Okay so i just added the page to codesandbox of how it looks currently. I've had no luck changing values to make the form under the first section. Either the first section gets loads of margin (displaying the gray background.) or it doesn't fill all the way to the left/right

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-architecture-z8odxs?file=/style.css

Comment: The reason why your stuff has a grey block on the left is because the `<div class="container">` your thing is in has a weird max-width forcing it to align center and having white spaces arround it.